# Expect script skipping wrong password

Tags: expect

I have the following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
set port "23"
set user "admin"
set password "1234"
set ip_file "devices"
set fid [open $ip_file r]
while {[gets $fid ip] != -1} {
spawn telnet $ip $port
expect "'^]'." sleep .1;
send "\r";
sleep .1;
expect   "login:"
send "$user\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r"
expect "#\r"
send "conf\r"
send "username root privilege 15 password toor\r"
send "no username admin\r"
send "end\r"
send "wr\r"
send "y\r"
send "exit\r"
expect eof

}
close $fid
```

I need to know how to skip to next ip from "devices" if password incorrect.Also to write that ip of device where password was incorrect on a local file from where the script was executed.

Thanks!

Comment: What is output to the screen when an incorrect password is entered?

Comment: Hello sir.

Here is the output : 

    Connected to 192.168.0.10.
       Escape character is '^]'.
       login:admin
       Password:********
       login:

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's where you get into a more advanced use of the `expect` command: you pass it a *list* of pattern/action pairs: untested

```
expect "Password:"
send "$password\r"
expect {
    "login:" {
        # bad password: hit Ctrl-C and move on to the next IP
        send \x03
        expect eof
        continue
    }
    "#\r"
}
# we've seen the prompt so you can carry on with the rest of your script
```

In this case, expect will branch based on the **first** pattern it can find.

Comment: Thank you sir. Now i am stuck on other problem. I am scracthing my head  for making to work with multiple username and password. So if i have a username and password and it will not work, i want the script to go to the next username and password.  Thanks in advance!